# Exact solution of the Hubbard model in one-dimension

Tags: condensed-matter, resource-recommendations, hamiltonian, fermions, spin-models

Does anyone know a full and well-explained account on how to solve the one-dimensional Hubbard model? I understand that the first solution is given [here](https://journals.aps.org/prl/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevLett.20.1445), but it's a little bit involved.

Perhaps just for the simplest case, spinless fermions with no magnetic fields,
is it possible to obtain the full spectrum, or just the basis state is available analytically?